# WPF Localization bug - empty strings

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application i have implemented simple localization based on cultures (resx).
The problem is in some translations strings becomes just empty. They are translated.

I dont understand why it happens and i am looking for explanation.
Looks like they become empty when loading them to resource editor or just compile from resx.

I use .Net 4.0, and the problem language is French (however other translations work fine: english, hungarian, russian, ..)

EDIT: i dont have much experience in localization maybe i dont know somethign important (like something about some characters/encoding for specific language, or "accent").. Some screenshots in comments..

Comment: How do you know? How did you test? Souce code? Where's the differences between russian, french a.s.o.? It's pointless to guess all these things.

Comment: If you dont know how to implement culture localization to XAML i will not explain here, google..

Comment: What answer do you exactly expect from us with the information you give us? (= no code no samples of text that you want to see but it is blank in French??)

Comment: check that the resx file name for french is correct  xxx.fr.resx

Comment: here some pictures (sorry for incorrect format)
http://i.stack.imgur.com/eOULy.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/HdZWQ.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/oa51k.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/h5YKo.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/A7HiC.png

File named "Resources.FR-FR.resx

Comment: your screenshots make no sense.. you show the empty ui strings which should be L_Options_Whatever in the resx file, but your screenshot of the resx is for other strings?

Comment: from the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h5YKo.png - I only see values but no keys!?

Comment: No sorry, there are keys and its fine, but they have no values. And VALUES ARE PRESENT IN RESX if i open with notepad. Sorry i took that screen shot inaccurate. L_About key has empty value  in resource editor (like many others) but in notepad it is fine.

Comment: have you tried to effectively use `À` instead of escaping it? If it's not on your keyboard, use the Windows Character Map to get it.

Comment: Lol. I love stackoverflow right after you ask something really not so stupid someone makes negative vote to your post.

Comment: @stijn your advice helped to solve the problem!!! I really didn't noticed that &.. Maybe you should post answer so i mark it as solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the actual characters (like `À`) instead of the escaped values. If the charactesr are not on your keyboard use the Character Map (Programs » Accessories » System Tools » Character Map) to get them.

Comment: it's alos possible that it does work with the escaped value, but that `&Agrave` is incorrect, you could try with `&#192;` maybe as well.